# Running snakefile from directory that doesn't contain snakefile

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm writing a pipeline that creates a snakefile in child directory.

The general structure looks like this.

```
> snakemake_pipeline.py
    > runs/
        > run1/
            > Snakefile
            > ... (all other necessary files for snakemake to run)
```

So, each time I run `snakemake_pipeline.py` a new directory is created in the `runs/` directory. I'd like to be able to run the snakefile in the `run1/` directory from the `snakemake_pipeline.py` script.

At the end of my script I've tried the following.

```
os.chidir(path/to/run1)
os.system(snakemake -j5)
```

The end result of this is snakemake gets started, but is unable to find all the files that are in the `run1/` directory.

I've also tried just

`snakemake runs/run1/Snakefile -j5`
and
`snakemake runs/run1/ -j5`

Both of which yield the same error
`Error: no Snakefile found, tried Snakefile, snakefile, workflow/Snakefile, workflow/snakefile.`

Comment: Mind that this violates [Best Practices](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/best_practices.html) and often pipelines can be restructed to rely on `snakemake` alone without the need of additional `Python` scripts which generate `Snakefile`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `--snakefile` or `-s` [option](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#execution).

```
snakemake --snakefile runs/run1/Snakefile
```

Comment: Great! I think that helps solve a big part of it. However, when I do this, it looks like it thinks the working directory is where I call it from. Is there any way to tell it that the working directory is the same dir that holds the snakefile?

Comment: @SamH: Have a look also at the `-d/--directory` option to set the working directory.